# Dynamically created BroadcastReceiver life cycle

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

BroadcastReceiver life cycle and operation is not clear to me, I already looked at android help library, but still it’s not clear, consider the following example:

```
private void sendSMS(final MessageInfo MI) {

    String SENT = "SMS_SENT" ;

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
            SENT), 0);

    // ---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Confirm(MI);
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "שליחה נכשלה",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "שליחה נכשלה, אין רשת",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "שליחה נכשלה, מצב טיסה",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(MI.Message());
    int numParts = parts.size();
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numParts; i++) {
        sentIntents.add(sentPI);
    }
    sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(MI.Phone(), null, parts, sentIntents, null);

}
}
```

What if I send a large number of messages, will it create a BroadcastReceiver for each message?
and when the sent confirmation is returned, is it return asynchronously or synchronously?
does the BroadcastReceiver unregister automatically, or does it need to be done manually?

I’ll appreciate any help, and I hope I am clear.

BTW
the Confirm function send confirmation to the server (asynchronously) and the MI class is MessageInfo(phone,body,ID)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What if I send a large number of messages, will it create a BroadcastReceiver for each message?

Yes. This is not a good idea. Please register it **ONCE**.

> and when the sent confirmation is returned, is it return asynchronously or synchronously?

Asynchronously.

> does the BroadcastReceiver unregister automatically

No.

> does it need to be done manually?

Yes, via `unregisterReceiver()`.